# To get server date and time

Tags: asp.net

i wrote the code to Fetch date and time from server not from client system. i write like this...

```
 DateTime dt = new DateTime();
 dt = DateTime.Now;
```

is this correct code?

Comment: use DateTime dt = DateTime.Now instead.!!

Comment: @Srinivas: I would say little or no difference once the compiler is done with it...!!

Comment: What do you intend to *use* the DateTime for?  In general on a server you normally want to use `DateTime.UtcNow` to avoid issues with timezones and daylight savings time changes when comparing DateTimes and so you can translate to a local time zone when presenting to a user on browser later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Invoking the `DateTime` constructor is not necessary. Use this instead:

```
var dt = DateTime.Now;
```

(This is equivalent, though slightly less verbose, than `DateTime dt = DateTime.Now`)

Comment: `DateTime.Now` is not a method.

Comment: This is still client side time not server.

Answer (score 1):

yes, use the DateTime.Now to obtain the current date and time on the machine where the program resides (in the case of ASP.NET the server).

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
 DateTime time = DateTime.Now;              
 string format = "MMM ddd d HH:mm yyyy";

 var dt = time.ToString(format);
```

Makes it aesthetically pleasing.
You can format with:

```
 MMM     display three-letter month 
 ddd     display three-letter day of the WEEK 
 d       display day of the MONTH 
 HH      display two-digit hours on 24-hour scale 
 mm      display two-digit minutes
 yyyy    display four-digit year
```

Of course you can use the NTP source namespace from Google. It's some source you can download:
http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc#GawBxmf1je8/NTP/NtpClient.cs&q=ntp%20lang:c%23&l=34

Comment: I need to say again! `DateTime.Now` is not a method.

Comment: Sorry bro, typing at warp speed.

Answer (score 0):

To get server time you need to make a class and need to modify it by server connection.

```
var my_date = ServerDateTime.GetServerDatetime().Date;
```

Get local time

```
var my_date = DateTime.Now;
```